# WordPress image upload Using ajax?

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I'm making front-end profiler in WordPress. I want to upload user photo from front-end. My entire profile is on WordPress ajax. I simply want to upload photo to `wp-content/uploads/..` but from front using ajax. I want two things:

1) Media hook

2) File to post through ajax

Can anyone help me a little. I'm really stuck in this place.

Comment: What do you mean by media hook? You want wordpress media uploader interface?

Comment: Yes, Hook from which i can upload image to my targeted directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First:**

For Wordpress new Media Uploader you should look to this [tutorial](http://www.lenslider.com/articles/wordpress-3-5-media-uploader-tips-on-using-it-within-plugins/).

**Second:**

To handle file uploads in Wordpress, you can use the function [wp_handle_upload](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload)

**Note:**

You can use [Form Data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) API to upload files with ajax but it may not work with older browsers. Instead you can do file uploads with iframe.

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick and suitable reply! can you give me a little push towards iFrame?