# How to refresh wordpress variation thumbnail?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Whenever a user is selecting a different product attribute I am generating a new photo and setting it for variation. The problem I have is that I do not know how to show a newly generated photo? If I reload the page and select the same attributes I get the needed image, but I want this to happen instantly after the user selects the attributes (and after the photo is generated).

Here are the fragments of the code I am using. Uploading an external link

```
$upload = wp_upload_bits( basename( $mockImageUrl), null, $response['body'] );
```

Generating an attachment and returning a new url:

```
$attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $upload["file"] );

    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

    $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $upload["file"]);   // we can think about removing this later
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $attachment_data );
    set_post_thumbnail( $variation_id, $attachment_id );

    echo json_encode($mockImageUrl);
```

Now new photo for variation is set, but the user still sees an old photo until refresh.

Comment: To update the current DOM without refreshing the page, you will have to use JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the current DOM without refreshing the page. you will have to upload image by using wordpress ajax. see below link.
[[WordPress image upload Using ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005630/wordpress-image-upload-using-ajax)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005630/wordpress-image-upload-using-ajax)

Comment: Thanks Gufran! This helped.